# How to protect shared prefrence data not to be clear at GC run?

Tags: android

My application `crashes` when i keep my application on `pause` for more than `15-20 min.`I have kept user credentials in `Shared preference`.  It is due to `shared preference` data which is cleared by GC. Can anyone suggest how get rid of this problem ?

```
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzbu(Unknown Source)
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1696)
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1671)
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4999)
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4594)
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4534)
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()' on a null object reference
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at com.google.android.gms.flags.impl.FlagProviderImpl.getBooleanFlagValue(Unknown Source)
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsd$zza.zzb(Unknown Source)
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsd$zza.zza(Unknown Source)
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsf.zzb(Unknown Source)
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsd.get(Unknown Source)
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.getInstance(Unknown Source)
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source) 
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzbu(Unknown Source) 
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1696) 
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1671) 
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source) 
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4999) 
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4594) 
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4534) 
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151) 
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364) 
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
06-08 05:04:52.913 4128-4128/org.openinfotech.home A/FirebaseApp:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

Comment: post your crash logs also.

Comment: What is crashes exception...add logcat here and I think GC never cleared shared prefernece data.. there is another problrm...So add some code

Comment: What makes you think your sharedpref data is being GCed?

Comment: I dnt know why it is getting crashed then @Tim Castelijns

Comment: i think it is due to shared preferences..!!

Comment: @ManpreetSingh gc doesnt clear shared preference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your logcat exception I think You are using Boolean some where in your class as a datatype. Change Boolean to **boolean**. Because boolean is a primitive data type whereas Boolean is an object/reference type that wraps a boolean.

boolean can be yes or no...Boolean can be yes, no or NULL

Hope this will help you.